# Calling MySQL Stored Procedure from FUSE doesn't work

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, fuse

I have a python class that inherits from fuse.Fuse that instantiates my MySQL wrapper (which has been separately unit tested and works).

I have implemented the fuse mkdir so that it calls a MySQL stored procedure to record the directories, the execution occurs and reports correctly but when I check the database nothing has occurred.

```
@logcall
def mkdir(self, path, mode):
    resultsSet, msg = self.__dbConn.CallStoredProcedure('AddDirectory', (path,))
    bklog.debug("AddDirectory param : {0}".format(path))
    bklog.debug("AddDirectory gave status of '{0}'".format(resultsSet[0]['Status']))
```

I am correctly getting the 'Directory successfully added' status in the logger showing the stored procedure has been executed:

```
DEBUG:bk_logging:AddDirectory param : /trial04
DEBUG:bk_logging:AddDirectory gave status of 'Directory successfully added'
DEBUG:mkdir:Called: mkdir(*(<FilesystemWrapper.FilesystemWrapper object at 0x10f479910>, '/trial04', 16877), **{}) on FilesystemWrapper() -> None
```

CallStoredProcedure() simply calls callproc() and it's value:

```
self.__mySQLCursor.callproc(procedureName, params)
resultsSet = ResultsSet()
results = self.__mySQLCursor.stored_results()
```

The initial creation for the mySQL wrapper is in the fuse.Fuse class member function fsinit().  As I have said, the wrapper outside of fuse works and has been for a long while, do I need to set a specific option/parameter to get this to work please?